# REST API for firestore with Google Identity OAuth 2.0 toke

Tags: api, oauth, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use REST API for firestore using following url
**https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{projectid}/databases/(default)/documents/products?key={apikey}**

current rule for database is

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

even after providing key I'm geting error as  "Missing or insufficient permissions.",

Answer (score 1):

Passing a key parameter in the REST API doesn't have anything to do with security rules.  The rule you're showing limits access to users in your app who are currently authenticated with Firebase Authentication and have a [Firebase ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#working_with_firebase_id_tokens):

> **Working with Firebase ID tokens**
>
> You can attain a Firebase ID token in two ways:
>
> - Generate a Firebase ID token using the Firebase Authentication REST API.
> - Retrieve a user's Firebase ID token from a Firebase Authentication SDK.
>
> By retrieving a user's Firebase ID token, you can make requests on
>   behalf of the user.
>
> *For requests authenticated with a Firebase ID token and for
>   unauthenticated requests, Cloud Firestore uses your Cloud Firestore
>   Security Rules to determine if a request is authorized.*

If you're trying to authenticate with either a Firebase or Oauth token, you should pass it as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authenticating_with_an_access_token):

> **Authenticating with an access token**
>
> After you obtain either a Firebase ID token or a Google Identity OAuth
>   2.0 token, pass it to the Cloud Firestore endpoints as an Authorization header set to Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}.

Note that authenticating with a service account always bypasses all security rules.  They only apply to Firebase users, or unauthenticated access.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are trying to use security rules on your project, but according to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security), I assume is either Authenticated private or User private.

For Authenticated private you can use

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

And for User private

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
```

Naturally, for the ladder you would have to send this userId on your url as well.

Let me know if this fixes your issue with permissions.

Comment: Want implement with Google oAuth , instead of Auth.

Comment: In that case I suggest checking the answer provided by @Doug Stevenson: If you are using Google oAuth, you should use an access token and send it to the Cloud Firestore enpoint as an Authorization header set to Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}.